# How to add button in laravel backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

Hello anyone can help add button like this in backpack?
thank!

add button by Inspect element.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to easily add a new button next to the Add button using `$this->crud->addButtonFromView()`. Check out a full example here: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.5/crud-buttons#adding-a-custom-button-with-a-blade-file

Please note that buttons are inserted in [one of the 3 stacks](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.5/crud-buttons#about) (top, bottom, line). As far as I can tell, you're trying to add to the `top` stack.

Hope it helps.